# Unable to set the OpenMP threads affinity in a forked process

Tags: c, linux, fork, openmp, libgomp

I am trying to run two processes on separate CPUs using openMP. In this case each CPU has 6 cores with hyper-threading (so 12 hardware threads). They need to do some synchronization which seems some what easier if they know each other's PID. So I am starting a process `sigC` from `sigS` using a `fork()` and `execve()` called with a different value for the `GOMP_CPU_AFFINITY` environment variable. After the `fork()/execve()` call, `sigS` has the correct affinity still but `sigC` prints

```
libgomp: no cpus left for affinity setting
```

and all threads are on the same core.

The code of `sigS`:

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <omp.h>
#include <sched.h>

int main( void )
{
   omp_set_num_threads(12); //12 hardware threads per CPU
   //this loop runs as expected
   #pragma omp parallel for
   for( int i = 0; i<12; i++ ) {
      #pragma omp critical 
      {
         printf("TEST PRE-FORK: I am thread %2d running on core %d\n",
                omp_get_thread_num(), sched_getcpu());
      }
   }

   pid_t childpid = fork();

   if( childpid < 0 ) {
      perror("Fork failed");
   } else {
      if( childpid == 0 ) { //<------ attempt to set affinity for child
         //change the affinity for the other process so it runs
         //on the other cpu
         char ompEnv[] = "GOMP_CPU_AFFINITY=6-11 18-23"; 
         char * const args[]    = { "./sigC", (char*)0 };
         char * const envArgs[] = { ompEnv,   (char*)0 };
         execve(args[0], args, envArgs);
         perror("Returned from execve");
         exit(1);
      } else {
         omp_set_num_threads(12);
         printf("PARENT: my pid     = %d\n", getpid());
         printf("PARENT: child pid  = %d\n", childpid);
         sleep(5); //sleep for a bit so child process prints first

         //This loop gives the same thread core/pairings as above
         //this is expected
         #pragma omp parallel for
         for( int i = 0; i < 12; i++ ) {
            #pragma omp critical
            {
               printf("PARENT: I'm thread %2d, on core %d.\n",
                      omp_get_thread_num(), sched_getcpu());
            }
         }
      }
   }
   return 0;
}
```

The code of `sigC` just has a omp parallel for loop in it but for completeness:

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <omp.h>
#include <sched.h>

int main( void )
{
   omp_set_num_threads(12);
   printf("CHILD: my pid     = %d\n", getpid());
   printf("CHILD: parent pid = %d\n", getppid());
   //I expect this loop to have the core pairings as I specified in execve
   //i.e thread 0 -> core 6, 1 -> 7, ... 6 -> 18, 7 -> 19 ... 11 -> 23
   #pragma omp parallel for
   for( int i = 0; i < 12; i++ ) {
      #pragma omp critical
      {
         printf("CHILD: I'm thread %2d, on core %d.\n",
                omp_get_thread_num(), sched_getcpu());
      }
   }
   return 0;
}
```

The output:

```
$ env GOMP_CPU_AFFINITY="0-5 12-17" ./sigS
```

This part is as expected

```
TEST PRE-FORK: I'm thread  0, on core 0.
TEST PRE-FORK: I'm thread 11, on core 17.
TEST PRE-FORK: I'm thread  5, on core 5.
TEST PRE-FORK: I'm thread  6, on core 12.
TEST PRE-FORK: I'm thread  3, on core 3.
TEST PRE-FORK: I'm thread  1, on core 1.
TEST PRE-FORK: I'm thread  8, on core 14.
TEST PRE-FORK: I'm thread 10, on core 16.
TEST PRE-FORK: I'm thread  7, on core 13.
TEST PRE-FORK: I'm thread  2, on core 2.
TEST PRE-FORK: I'm thread  4, on core 4.
TEST PRE-FORK: I'm thread  9, on core 15.
PARENT: my pid     = 11009
PARENT: child pid  = 11021
```

This is the problem - all threads in the child run on core 0

```
libgomp: no CPUs left for affinity setting
CHILD: my pid     = 11021
CHILD: parent pid = 11009
CHILD: I'm thread  1, on core 0.
CHILD: I'm thread  0, on core 0.
CHILD: I'm thread  4, on core 0.
CHILD: I'm thread  5, on core 0.
CHILD: I'm thread  6, on core 0.
CHILD: I'm thread  7, on core 0.
CHILD: I'm thread  8, on core 0.
CHILD: I'm thread  9, on core 0.
CHILD: I'm thread 10, on core 0.
CHILD: I'm thread 11, on core 0.
CHILD: I'm thread  3, on core 0.
```

(I omitted the parent thread printing as it is the same as the pre-fork)

Any ideas on how I can fix this or if it is the right approach?

Comment: Please, always check if your code samples compile before posting them here as compile errors might frustrate those who try to solve your problem. In both sources there is a comma instead of dot in `errno.h` and also there is a typo (`/` instead of `//`) in the source code of `sigS`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `fork()`-ed child process inherits its parent affinity mask. `libgomp` intersects this affinity mask with the set from `GOMP_CPU_AFFINITY` and ends up with an empty set as both sets are complementary. This behaviour is not documented, but a look at the source code of `libgomp` confirms that this is indeed the case.

The solution is to reset the affinity mask of the child process before it makes the `execve()` call:

```
if (childpid == 0) { //<------ attempt to set affinity for child
   cpu_set_t *mask;
   size_t size;
   int nrcpus = 256; // 256 CPUs should be more than enough

   // Reset the CPU affinity mask
   mask = CPU_ALLOC(nrcpus);
   size = CPU_ALLOC_SIZE(nrcpus);
   for (int i = 0; i < nrcpus; i++)
      CPU_SET_S(i, size, mask);
   if (sched_setaffinity(0, size, mask) == -1) { handle error }
   CPU_FREE(mask);

   //change the affinity for the other process so it runs
   //on the other cpu
   char ompEnv[] ="GOMP_CPU_AFFINITY=6-11 18-23"; 
   char * const args[]    = {"./sigC", (char*)0};
   char * const envArgs[] = {ompEnv,   (char*)0};
   execve(args[0], args, envArgs);
   perror("Returned from execve");
   exit(1);
} else {
```